# How to order by another model's value in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

OverstockEntities.cs

```
namespace Overstock.Models
{
    public class OverstockEntities: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Product.cs

```
    namespace Overstock.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "ProductId")]
    public class Product
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Brand")]
        public int BrandId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Product title is required")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Price is required")]
        [Range(0.01, 100000.00,
            ErrorMessage="Price must be between 0.01 and 100000.00")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Product Art URL")]
        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Category.cs

```
    namespace Overstock.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Browse action

```
public ActionResult Browse(string category, string sortOrder)
        {
            var varCategories = MyDB.Categories.Include("Products").Single(c => c.Name == category);
            //How to order by Product's Title value
            return View(varCategories);
        }
```

Question: how to get another model's variable(in this case Product.Title) in order to sort by that variable?

Comment: why you want order by product title now ? Can't you use orderBy when you use your products list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var category in varCategories )
        {
            category.Products = category.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Title);
        }
```

Comment: In his case varCategories is single, so the loop is uncesseray